# Lenovo B560 AMD processor screen problems

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, xubuntu

My good old B560 ran all Xubuntu versions until 18.04 when the screen flickered a lot but still ran.  After 19.04 installation, every attempt to run it ended with black screen.  Re-installing 18.04 then produced same result. Have now read excellent stuff about nomodeset, nvidia, etc and am trying solutions suggested....but is there a permanent fix or will I have to do the fix every time I boot ?

Comment: `nomodeset` isn't a fix, it's a temporary workaround.

Comment: Well thanks,  but I still have the problem.  What's the permanent solution ?

Comment: You should have kept 18.04.